# oh-my-bash not launching at terminal startup

Tags: bash

A little while ago I updated to the newest version of bash on my macbook (all went smoothly there,) and decided to try out the oh-my-bash framework. I had previously used oh-my-zsh, so I was familiar with the installation; however, I'm running into an annoying problem with oh-my-bash.

When I open the terminal the framework doesn't launch automatically. It only launches if I run `exec bash` in the command line. I've checked in system preferences and bash is set as default, and running `bash --version` confirms that I am running the correct version of bash when the terminal starts up.

It's more of an inconvenience than anything else, but I'm learning scripting and my burning curiosity wants to find the solution. I'm out of ideas short of a fresh install of the framework; what do you guys think?

Comment: I suspect "oh-my-bash" made changes to your `~/.bashrc` (or maybe called `~/.bash_bashrc` on your Mac -- dunno). After you `exec bash`, open your `.bashrc` and look for any changes and comment them out or delete them. Personally, I've never seen the need for any "oh-my...anything". Set your run-control file up to do what you *Need* (carefully). Don't let somebody else's "oh-my-stuff" touch it. You are the admin for your account in that regard. Never allow configurations to be added or changed that you don't know exactly what is being changed and what the result will be.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is this:

1. Run this code in terminal

```bash
mv $HOME/.bashrc $HOME/bash_profile
```

2. Restart your terminal

In linux, bash run command file is `.bashrc`, but in MacOS is `.bash_profile`.